# How to modify a textview from a different process ?

Tags: python, twitter, gtk, pygtk, multiprocessing

So I am making a GUI to get tweets. I have made an event box which would take the signal and change the textview.
I am using multiprocessing to change the textview, but it just doesn't change. I even tried changing the size of the window. But nothing changes. I can get textbuffer of the textview but can not change it.

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
from multiprocessing import Process

class multi:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.window.set_size_request(800,400)
        self.window.set_title("Twitter Box")
        self.window.set_border_width(4)
        self.window.connect("destroy", self.close_application)

        self.vbox1 = gtk.EventBox()
        self.vbox1.set_size_request(750,450)
        self.vbox1.connect('leave_notify_event',self.go_multi)
        self.window.add(self.vbox1)
        self.vbox1.show()

        self.tweetview = gtk.TextView()
        self.tweetbuffer = self.tweetview.get_buffer()
        self.tweetbuffer.set_text('Why not working?')
        self.vbox1.add(self.tweetview)
        self.tweetview.show()

        self.window.show()

    def close_application(self, widget):
        gtk.main_quit()

    def go_multi(self, widget, data=None):
        p = Process(target = self.change_textview)
        p.start()
        p.join()

    def change_textview(self):
        print 'changing text'
        startiter = self.tweetbuffer.get_start_iter()
        enditer = self.tweetbuffer.get_end_iter()
        text = self.tweetbuffer.get_text(startiter, enditer)
        print text
        if text:
            self.tweetbuffer.set_text('Changed....')
        else:
            self.tweetbuffer.set_text('')
        return 

def main():
    multi()
    gtk.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am making GUI to get tweets. Sometimes it takes really long to retrieve timeline due to slow connectivity and the GUI freezes. So, I wanted to make it such that, it would create a process and it will fetch the timeline and set tweetbuffer. But I am unable to set text in tweetbuffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't fully inderstand why you do this:

```
def go_multi(self, widget, data=None):
    p = Process(target = self.change_textview)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

because, even in the remote possibility in which it should work, you're basically calling the `change_textview` function and waiting for the process to finish.

Cleared this, I don't think you need multiprocessing at all, make your gui multithreading instead.

Make a Gtk multithread may be a little tricky at first, but it's not a difficult task.
You have two ways for doing so:

1. Update your widget using `GLib.idle_add` (or `GObject.idle_add`, I never fully understand why sometimes they're not the same)
2. Or follow what's explained [[here]](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk-faq/stable/x481.html). Which it basically says to:

   - Call the following methods before you call `Gtk.main()`:

     ```
      GObject.threads_init()
      Gdk.threads_init()
     ```
   - In your thread, surround the code that updates the Gtk widgets with:

     ```
      Gdk.threads_enter()
      # your code here
      Gdk.threads_leave()
     ```

Comment: Thanks! It is helping me a lot. I once tried multithreading, but it didn't work very well. So, I tried mutliprocessing.
Now I am going for multithreading

Comment: @Froyo: Would this mean that you're going to accept and/or up-vote my answer? :D

Answer (score 2):

You must run the main loop to process the rendering events before anything becomes visible.

Also, you must not call GTK functions from a second thread.

Read this to get you started: [Multi-threaded GTK applications – Part 1: Misconceptions](http://blogs.operationaldynamics.com/andrew/software/gnome-desktop/gtk-thread-awareness)

And here is how to apply this knowledge to PyGTK: [Threads on PyGTK](http://aruiz.typepad.com/siliconisland/2006/04/threads_on_pygt.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to continue on that way after all answers:
**Disclaimer:** 
I have no idea how useful this answer. 
**Explanation:** 
I tried to use your logic. I also imported `Queue` to share some data between processes. I guess it was needed as I saw from [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html). You may find some other info in code sample below.

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

class multi:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.window.set_size_request(800,400)
        self.window.set_title("Twitter Box")
        self.window.set_border_width(4)
        self.window.connect("destroy", self.close_application)

        self.vbox1 = gtk.EventBox()
        self.vbox1.set_size_request(750,450)
        self.vbox1.connect('leave_notify_event',self.go_multi)
        self.window.add(self.vbox1)
        self.vbox1.show()
        self.tweetview = gtk.TextView()
        self.tweetbuffer = self.tweetview.get_buffer()
        self.tweetbuffer.set_text('Why not working?')
        self.vbox1.add(self.tweetview)
        self.tweetview.show()

        self.window.show()

    def close_application(self, widget):
        gtk.main_quit()

    def go_multi(self, widget, data=None):
        q = Queue()
        p = Process(target = self.change_textview, args=(q,))
        p.start()
        self.tweetbuffer.set_text(q.get())
        p.join()

    def change_textview(self, q):
        print 'changing text'
        startiter = self.tweetbuffer.get_start_iter()
        enditer = self.tweetbuffer.get_end_iter()
        text = self.tweetbuffer.get_text(startiter, enditer)
        print text
        if text:
            q.put(('Changed....'))
        else:
            q.put((''))
def main():
    multi()
    gtk.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: go_mulit() is called everytime the mouse pointer moves away from the eventbox!